# Help understanding a proof from Zurich Analysis book I

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I just learned the Rank theorem as its written in Zurich Analysis book I:

(The rank theorem) Let $ f:U\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $  be a mapping defined in a neighborhood $ U\subset\mathbb{R}^{m} $ of a point   $ x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{m} $

if $ f\in C^{(p)}\left(U;\mathbb{R}^{n}\right),  p\geq1 $   and the mapping
f has the same rank k at every point $ x\in U $ then there exist neighborhoods  $ O\left(x_{0}\right) $  of $ x_0 $ and $O(y_0)$ of $y_0=f(x_0) $ and  diffeomorphisms $ u=\varphi(x) $,$v=\psi(y) $ of those neighborhoods, of class $C^(p) $ such that the mapping  $ v=\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}\left(u\right) $ has the coordinate representation $ \left(u^{1},...u^{k},...,u^{m}\right)\to v=\left(v^{1},...,v^{n}\right)=\left(u^{1},...,u^{k},0,..,0\right) $.

Now as a remark for this theorem, in the book there is a claim that if the rank of the mapping $ f:U\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $

is exactly $ n $ at every point of the original neighborhood $ U\subset \mathbb{R}^m $  (the same as the dimension of the range)

then the point $ y_0=f(x_0) $ where $ x_0 \in U $, is an interior point of $f(U) $. In other words, $ f(U) $ is an open set.

This is the proof:

From the rank theorem the mapping in our case of $n=k $ has the form

$ \psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}\left(u^{1},...,u^{m}\right)=\left(u^{1},...,u^{n}\right) $

and so the image of a neighborhood of $u_0=\varphi(x_0) $ contains some neighborhood of $ v_0=\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^-1(u_0) $ .

But the mappings $ \varphi:O(x_0) \to O(u_0) $ and $ \psi:O(y_0) \to O(v_0) $ are diffeomorphisms and thereofre they map interior points to interior points. writing the original mapping $ f $ as $ f=\psi^{-1}\circ\left(\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}\right)\circ\varphi $ we conclude that $ y_0=f(x_0) $ is an interior point of the image of a neighborhood of $ x_0 $.

I do not understand this proof actually. How does the fact that $ k=n $ helps us? what would be different if $k $ was smaller than $ n $ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because $(u^1, \dots , u^m)\mapsto (u^1, \dots , u^n)$ is open, wheras $(u^1, \dots , u^m)\mapsto (u^1, \dots , u^k, 0, \dots, 0)$ is not.

Comment: The proof boils down to saying composition of open maps are open.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Im not familier with the term "open maps" do you mean a map from an open set to an open set? if so, why is $ (u^1,...,u^m)\to (u^1,...,u^k,0,...,0) $ is not open?

Comment: No, the *image* of every open set in the domain has to be open in the codomain. If you map $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ by $f(u^1,u^2)=(u^1,0)$, then the $u^1$-axis is NOT open in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. I understand now why  $n<k$ dosent work. But why exactly $ n=k $ does work? what makes $ f(U) $ an open set?

Comment: When $n=k$, the mapping now looks like a projection map $\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$ and such a map is always open. It suffices to check on a basic open set, so take an appropriate product open set and project it.

Comment: @TedShifrin I just cant understand, if we are writing $ f $ as $ f=\psi^{-1}\circ\psi\circ f\circ\varphi^{-1}\circ\varphi $ then always for any $ x \in U(x_0) $ we have $ f\left(x\right)=\psi^{-1}\left(\zeta\right) $ for some $ \zeta\in U\left(v_{0}\right) $ so where is the mistake here?

Comment: Go back to my original example. You cannot show that every point in a ball around the origin is in the image of $f$.